# The fate of an ASP.NET control

Tags: asp.net, barcode

A long time ago, in a country far far away ... I created an ASP.NET control, that now lives in the dungeons of my hard drive. It's a fairly well tested and stable control, that fulfills a very specialized task. I'd like to do something with this control, and I can already think of these:

1. Commercialize it. Making a profit is always good, but since I don't have a company, and don't want to create one for this small purpose, how can I do this legally without too much overhead? Is there a marketplace, or an "eBay" for ASP.NET controls? It will also take some more work to make it ready for this, as I'd have to write some more documentation, possibly create a trial version, and optionally incorporate licensing and obfuscate the control.
2. Open source it. Contribute the code to the world. Given the specific niche that the control fulfills, I don't expect any contributions from peers, though. And yes, there are still many ways to evolve the control.
3. Give it away for free. This way, I could perhaps attract the intangibles of peer recognition and reputation, which is always a good thing. What's the most visible place to post it?

What would you do?

**UPDATE:**

A couple of components marketplaces have appeared. I know of [binpress](http://www.binpress.com/) and [codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/).

My control is a barcode control (one for ASP.NET and one for Windows Forms) that I've put on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/nbarcodes/).

Comment: If it's that long ago, are you refering to a .NET 1.1 control? I would say upgrade it and open-source it!

Comment: You could try to commercialize it, however I would wager that you would get more benefits to it in the long run if you open sourced it. If it's truly a great control, you'll get the peer recognition benefit as well.

Comment: You might lose more 'blood' trying to build a platform to sell and support it. Share with the world!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to open source it a great place would be http://www.CodePlex.com, there you could post your project, the source code and accept community contributions....

Also I believe that CodePlex has a system in place where you could get revenue generated from ads that get displayed in your project workspace...

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to go the 'free' route, I highly recommend using it to to drive traffic to your blog/site.  Go talk it up, and start ushering people to your web presence to share your solution and to benefit from the fruits of your labor.  You receive exposure and potentially profitable traffic in return (through traffic/click/affiliate monetization).

Here is another route I saw from Brian Pautsch a while back with his Sitemap Generator tool.  He started off in a free beta to gauge interest and help work out any remaining kinks.  Then he moved to a reasonably priced pay model.  His traffic skyrocketed during the free phase, and remained through the paid version.

Look, your (developers in general) time and expertise is valuable.  It is a noble thing to earn money from a great idea or a solution to a problem.  Good luck, and be sure to update us on what you decide!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have ambitions to sell more controls like this, I'd give it away for free.  Assuming it's quality work, the benefits of peer recognition probably outweigh the net benefit of selling it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always open source it and then offer support services for a fee to try and get the best of both worlds. If it's a niche area then they wouldn't have many other offerings to compare it with and your services may be more in demand.